# How to partially fill an SVG element in isotype chart

Tags: d3.js

I am tying to modify the example isotype (pictogram) chart in d3.js found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/d832fc03f6e6a91e99f4). I would like to know how to partially fill an icon based upon the decimal remainder from a value that is sent in. For example if I have 50 icons and my value sent is in 5% then I would expect 2 icons to be completely filled an the next icon to be half-filled with the fill color. My current code just uses a function to take in a percentage to fill the icons as it is in the example:

```
function drawIsotype(dataObject) {
    valueLit = dataObject.unemprate;
    total = numCols * numRows;
    valuePict = total * (dataObject.unemprate / 100);

    d3.select("#txtValue").text(valueLit + '%');
    d3.selectAll("use").attr("class", function (d, i) {
        if (d < valuePict) {
            return "iconSelected";
        } else {
            return "iconPlain";
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code so far:

```
//create svg element
var svgDoc = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("viewBox", "0 0 100 100");

// Define the gradient
var gradient = svgDoc.append("svg:defs")
    .append("svg:linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("y1", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "0%")
    .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

// Define the gradient colors
gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "white")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("svg:stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "orange")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

//define an icon store it in svg <defs> elements as a reusable component - this geometry can be generated from Inkscape, Illustrator or similar
svgDoc.append("defs")
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "iconCustom")
    .attr('fill', 'url(#gradient)')
    .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M3.5,2H2.7C3,1.8,3.3,1.5,3.3,1.1c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9H1.1C0.7,2,0.4,2.3,0.4,2.6v1.9c0,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.6h0.2c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1v1.9c0,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.6h1.3c0.2,0,0.3-0.3,0.3-0.6V5.3c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1h0.2c0.3,0,0.6-0.3,0.6-0.6V2.6C4.1,2.3,3.8,2,3.5,2z");


//background rectangle
svgDoc.append("rect").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100);

//specify the number of columns and rows for pictogram layout
var numCols = 10;
var numRows = 5;

//padding for the grid
var xPadding = 10;
var yPadding = 15;

//horizontal and vertical spacing between the icons
var hBuffer = 9;
var wBuffer = 8;

//generate a d3 range for the total number of required elements
var myIndex = d3.range(numCols * numRows);



//text element to display number of icons highlighted
svgDoc.append("text")
    .attr("id", "txtValue")
    .attr("x", xPadding)
    .attr("y", yPadding)
    .attr("dy", -3)
    .text("0");

//create group element and create an svg <use> element for each icon
svgDoc.append("g")
    .attr("id", "pictoLayer")
    .selectAll("use")
    .data(myIndex)
    .enter()
    .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", "#iconCustom")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            return "icon" + d;
        })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            var remainder = d % numCols;//calculates the x position (column number) using modulus
            return xPadding + (remainder * wBuffer);//apply the buffer and return value
        })
          .attr("y", function (d) {
              var whole = Math.floor(d / numCols)//calculates the y position (row number)
              return yPadding + (whole * hBuffer);//apply the buffer and return the value
          })
        .classed("iconPlain", true);

var data = { percent: 5.0 };

function drawIsotype(dataObject) {
    valueLit = dataObject.percent;
    total = numCols * numRows;
    valuePict = total * (dataObject.percent / 100);

    d3.select("#txtValue").text(valueLit + '%');
    d3.selectAll("use").attr("class", function (d, i) {
        if (d < valuePict - 1) {
            return "iconSelected";
        } else {
            return "iconPlain";
        }
    });

    d3.selectAll("use").attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        valuePartial = Math.ceil(valuePict);
        valueDecimal = (valuePict % 1).toFixed(1);
        if (d == valuePartial) {
            console.log(valueDecimal);
            //return "iconSelected";
            return "url(#gradient" + valueDecimal + ")";
        }
    });
}
drawIsotype(data);
```

However, calling `return "url(#gradient" + valueDecimal + ")";` has no apparent affect. And it looks like the gradient fill is still overridding the change to the `iconSelected` class as well. I think I am missing something obvious but just not sure what. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/u3tjmy0b/2/) of my current code.

Comment: fill them with a linearGradient and manipulate the stop positions to change the amount of fill.

Comment: @RobertLongson Any tips on how to integrate that into this d3 syntax? This is my first deep dive into d3 and feeling really lost at the moment.

Comment: which bit are you stuck on? create the linearGradient, give it some child element stops, set their attributes, point the fill to the gradient.

Comment: I guess I am stuck on all of that. I tried adding a linear gradient via svg `append` but I got errors on 'y' not defined. I am not sure where to add the linear gradient "stuff". This is a current stripped down jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/u3tjmy0b/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your gradient dynamically.  Also, I would not try to fill with the fill attribute and the css class together:

```
    function drawIsotype(dataObject) {
        var valueLit = dataObject.percent,
        total = numCols * numRows,
        valuePict = total * (dataObject.percent / 100),
        valueDecimal = (valuePict % 1);

        d3.select("#txtValue").text(valueLit + '%');

        d3.selectAll("use").attr("fill", function (d, i) {              
            if (d < valuePict - 1) {                  
                return "orange"; //<-- solid orange
            } else if (d > (valuePict - 1) && d < (valuePict)){
              // create gradient dynamically
              // to stop at your percent
              gradient.append("svg:stop")
                .attr("offset", (valueDecimal * 100) + '%')
                .attr("stop-color", "orange")
                .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
              gradient.append("svg:stop")
                .attr("offset", (valueDecimal * 100) + '%')
                .attr("stop-color", "white")
                .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
             gradient.append("svg:stop")
                .attr("offset", '100%')
                .attr("stop-color", "white")
                .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
              return "url(#gradient)";
            } else {
                return "white"; //<-- white ones
            }              
        });
    }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3tjmy0b/4/).

Comment: that was the part I was unsure of - adding dynamically. This a great solution.